# What does the `is` keyword do in typescript?

Tags: typescript, keyword

I came across some code that looks like this:

```
export function foo(arg: string): arg is MyType {
    return ...
}
```

I haven't been able to search for `is` in either the docs or google, it's a pretty common word and shows up on basically every page.

What does the keyword do in that context?

Comment: I found this tutorial helpful: https://youtu.be/eJ6R1knfsoc?t=300

Watch from 5:00 to 6:50

Answer (score 416, accepted):

See the reference for [user-defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for more information.

```js
function isString(test: any): test is string{
    return typeof test === "string";
}

function example(foo: any){
    if(isString(foo)){
        console.log("it is a string" + foo);
        console.log(foo.length); // string function
    }
}
example("hello world");
```

Using the type predicate `test is string` in the above format (instead of just using `boolean` for the return type), after `isString()` is called, if the function returns `true`, **TypeScript will narrow the type to `string` in any block guarded by a call to the function.**
The compiler will think that `foo` is `string` in the below-guarded block (and ONLY in the below-guarded block)

```js
{
    console.log("it is a string" + foo);
    console.log(foo.length); // string function
}
```

A type predicate is just used in compile time. The resulting `.js` file (runtime) will have no difference because it does not consider the TYPE.

I will illustrate the differences in below four examples.

E.g 1:
the above example code will not have a compile error nor a runtime error.

E.g 2:
the below example code will have a compile error (as well as a runtime error) because TypeScript has narrowed the type to `string` and checked that `toExponential` does not belong to `string` method.

```js
function example(foo: any){
    if(isString(foo)){
        console.log("it is a string" + foo);
        console.log(foo.length);
        console.log(foo.toExponential(2));
    }
}
```

E.g. 3:
the below example code does not have a compile error but will have a runtime error because TypeScript will ONLY narrow the type to `string` in the block guarded but not after, therefore `foo.toExponential` will not create compile error (TypeScript does not think it is a `string` type). However, in runtime, `string` does not have the `toExponential` method, so it will have runtime error.

```js
function example(foo: any){
    if(isString(foo)){
        console.log("it is a string" + foo);
        console.log(foo.length);
    }
    console.log(foo.toExponential(2));
}
```

E.g. 4:
if we don’t use `test is string` (type predicate), TypeScript will not narrow the type in the block guarded and the below example code will not have compile error but it will have runtime error.

```js
function isString(test: any): boolean{
    return typeof test === "string";
}
function example(foo: any){
    if(isString(foo)){
        console.log("it is a string" + foo);
        console.log(foo.length);
        console.log(foo.toExponential(2));
    }
}
```

The conclusion is that `test is string` (type predicate) is used in compile-time to tell the developers the code will have a chance to have a runtime error. For javascript, the developers will not KNOW the error in compile time. This is the advantage of using TypeScript.

Answer (score 20):

The only use I know is the one of your example: specifying a "type predicate" (`arg is MyType`) in an user defined Type Guard

See User Defined Type Guards in this [reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Here is another [reference](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Comment: I saw this in the docs too, what a bizarre design decision, this case can totally be handled by returning a type `boolean` right?

Comment: @benjaminz I don't see how it could be handled by a boolean. Typescript needs to know that the function into which you pass an object is functioning like a type guard. If it just returns type true or false, how can Typescript know that it's indeed a type guard and not just some arbitrary function that returns true if the object is truthy. How will it know to narrow the object's type? Second, how can it know what type to narrow the object's type to? What if the parameter is one of three types? It needs to know that `true` corresponds to a specific type.

Comment: Okay maybe returning boolean won't work, but why not implement 'is' operator? Instead of writing `function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}; if (isFish(pet)){fish.swim()}` we could just write `if (pet is Fish){fish.swim()}`.

Comment: On the other side, type guards are bad from the standpoint of OOP. So, maybe this boilerplate is a scarecrow for those who want to do crazy typecasts. If you want to check a variable type, probably you should revise your architecture. If you still want type-checking, maybe you deserve suffering:)

Comment: @rkuksin TypeScript just can't known if pet is a Fish.