# How to check if string in type

Tags: typescript, types

I have the type:

```
export type PermissionType = 'creator' | 'editor' | 'viewer'
```

At run time, how to check if a variable userInput is actually one the type above

```
let userInput = 'foo' //
isOfTypePermission(userInput)  // should return false or throw an error

let userInput2 = 'creator'
isOfTypePermission(userInput2) // should return true
```

In other word, how to get the type **PermissionType** compiled into a javascript array so that I can just do **indexOf(userInput) > -1**

Comment: You'll want to use a switch statement

Comment: You can't have PermissionType compiled into a javascript array, but you can get the type inferred from the values in an array.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't over-complicate it.

```
function isOfTypePermission (userInput: string): userInput is PermissionType {
  return ['creator', 'editor', 'viewer'].includes(userInput);
}
```

See [What does the `is` keyword do in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081332/what-does-the-is-keyword-do-in-typescript) for more information on why we don't just use a `boolean` return type.

If your `PermissionType` is really long, then it might be worth it to infer the type from a `const` value instead.

```
const permissions = ['creator', 'editor', 'viewer'] as const;
type PermissionType = (typeof permissions)[number];

function isOfTypePermission (userInput: string): userInput is PermissionType {
  return (permissions as readonly string[]).includes(userInput);
}
```

Or possibly even a `Set`

```
const permissions = new Set(['creator', 'editor', 'viewer'] as const);
type PermissionType = typeof permissions extends Set<infer T> ? T : never;

function isOfTypePermission (userInput: string): userInput is PermissionType {
  return (permissions as Set<string>).has(userInput);
}
```

Comment: This is why I love algebraic types and I wish other languages supported it too!

Comment: Is there something generic/dynamic for that, 
Because in that particular case the list could be updated and need to remember updating it.

Comment: @Bleicher The question was about a type which is a string literal union. Sounds like you wouldn't be able to actually restrict the type if you determined the value was contained in a list which is runtime dynamic. You'd still only know that it was a `string`.