# Is there a way to check for type equality in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to get an error if two types don't match. 
I have an object:

```
const ACTIVITY_ATTRIBUTES = {
    onsite: {
        id:  "applied",
        ....
    },
    online: {
        id: "applied_online",
        ....
    },
    ...
} as const
```

I'd like it to be limited to the strings the server can accept

```
export type ContactAttribute = "applied" | "applied_online" | "donated" | "messaged" | "reviewed"
```

I know as const can't go with a type limitation (as const will be ignored). But is there a way to to check for type equality, to enforce that the id property is of type ContactAttribute? Something like:

```
$Values<typeof ACTIVITY_ATTRIBUTES >["id"] === ContactAttribute
```

Answer (score 4):

This could be achieved using a dummy validating function.

```
const validateType = <T> (obj:T) => undefined
```

All that is left is to call it with the type and object:

```
type ContactAttribute = "applied" | "applied_online" | "donated" | "messaged" | "reviewed"

type ActivityAttributes= {
   [k:string]: {
      id: ContactAttribute 
   }
}

const ACTIVITY_ATTRIBUTES = {
    onsite: {
        id:  "applied",
        ....
    },
    donation: {
        id: "donated",
        ....
    },
    ...
} as const

validateType<ActivityAttributes>(ACTIVITY_ATTRIBUTES) // Will show an error if types don't match.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd come up with a helper function that only accepts arguments whose properties have an `id` property of type `ContactAttribte`, and returns its argument untouched, and without changing its type:

```
const hasGoodContactAttributes =
    <T extends Record<keyof T, { id: ContactAttribute }>>(t: T) => t;
```

Then you'd create `ACTIVITY_ATTRIBUTES` like this:

```
const ACTIVITY_ATTRIBUTES = hasGoodContactAttributes({
    onsite: {
        id: "applied",
        otherProp: 123,
    },
    donation: {
        id: "donated",
        alsoOtherProp: 456
        //....
    },
    online: {
        id: "applied_online",
        //....
    },
    reviewe: {
        id: "reviewed",
        //....
    },
}); // as const if you want
```

If you make a mistake, you'll get an error:

```
const BAD_ATTRIBUTES = hasGoodContactAttributes({
    okay: {
        id: "messaged"
    },
    oops: {
        id: "reviewed_online" // error!
    //  ~~ <-- '"reviewed_online"' is not assignable to type 'ContactAttribute'
    }
})
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwMbAILGAJwJYBGArsNALxQBEyYYANnhACaVQA+VN9jTA+ogwQRWHSk0TJSLdgFgAUFEVUAthADOa5AHNmIqjggA3RgHddAbnlR5qRGuBQAFsjUBxOHCbwkaTNnzEpGpQZFZKADwAKlAQAB6kCEzBAEoQtjhM4QDWECBwAGZQkQA0UADeUHhMAFywiCjoWLiEJNAAvgB8HQAUwLWRAJQhHVDAlnI2dg4YMJEAkgBqc5EAmrwYkZHJcwBCAKqRAKIAyiFOLu6e3g1+zYHq3WVhinZ4pLVPCkrfVbXUtAxdMVnt8oHBgI4IDgAAo4OBgWoARgATABmYFfRRtDHfcQISR4RAfEE-GpUPGSIEkpTIOhqOAAeQhUNh8NqABYAKwANmpigA9PyAHQioUg7EggR4ITEzGg36cAE8fgIQTCHGggXC0XijWKAzGCBmWWaxQKygG0xUuXfQWisVyiVyNoDcxQQVQFxQWwIeyVQp5IhQEzIJDySa+hw7DAAEXWm22+yOpwozjcHi89V8TQCrTUj0lWWQIBNpvNqg02l0usl8LUpc15stRuYKrVrA9ULhOAAhCCPVAAH6DqDhAC0Y6gAHILUYrXwpUJKFPKsEEODPRo8Fp8QQ6NBgHBRuBoFPrtn-C1SFPxfIXUA)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573087/typescript-check-if-value-is-contained-in-type) to know a easier way to achieve this.

Something like:

```
const ACTIVITY_ATTRIBUTES = {
    onsite: {
        id:  "applied",
    },
    donation: {
        id: "donated",
    },
    online: {
        id: "applied_online",
    },
    reviewe: {
        id: "reviewed",
    },
}

export type ContactAttribute = "applied" | "applied_online" | "donated" | "messaged" | "reviewed"

function isOfTypeContact (inputId: string): inputId is ContactAttribute {
    return ["applied", "applied_online", "donated", "messaged", "reviewed"].includes(inputId);
}

console.log(isOfTypeContact(ACTIVITY_ATTRIBUTES.onsite.id)) // true
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a combination of `declare` and dead code. The `declare` statements are purely compile time so we use those to set up fake "values" of our types. Then we use a dead code block to call a function that takes two parameters of the same type.

```
type T1 = number;
type T2 = string;

declare const dummy1: T1;
declare const dummy2: T2;
declare function sameType<T>(v1: T, v2: T): void;
if (false) {
    // @ts-ignore: Unreachable code
    sameType(
        // prevent line break so that the ts-ignore is only applied to the above line
        dummy1, dummy2);
}
```

The `@ts-ignore` is to silence the unreachable code error.

I added a line comment after `(` to prevent tools like prettier from putting the arguments on the same line which would silence the error you want to achieve.

You can also use an `as` expression which might be a little bit more concise.

```
type T1 = number;
type T2 = string;

declare const dummy1: T1;
if (false) {
    // @ts-ignore: Unreachable code
    dummy1 
        // prevent line break so that the ts-ignore is only applied to the above line
        as T2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve that by using the following code:

```
const ACTIVITY_ATTRIBUTES: {[key: string]: {id: ContactAttribute}} = {
    onsite: {
        id:  "applied",
    },
    donation: {
        id: "donated",
    },
    online: {
        id: "applied_online",
    },
    reviewe: {
        id: "reviewed",
    },
    hi: {
      id: 'applied',
    }
} as const

type ContactAttribute = "applied" | "applied_online" | "donated" | "messaged" | "reviewed"
```

However, I suspect this might want more typechecking than this, because with the solution above, even the `id` can be checked properly, you still can have falsy property placed for different `id`.

To avoid this issue, you might want to use [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

For example:

```
type Contact = {
  id: "applied",
  x: string
} | {
  id: "applied_online"
  y: number
}
```

By leveraging this feature, you can make sure that the expected properties associated with each `ContactAttribute` would be initialised correctly.