# How to check for type equality in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

*While searching for how to test for type equality in TypeScript, I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59346116/is-there-a-way-to-check-for-type-equality-in-typescript) whose title looked promising, but whose actual question was not about testing for type equality.*

I would like something that can test two types for equivalency:

```
type IsEqual<Type1, Type2> = ???;
```

It could be used, for example, to determine the return type of an overloaded function:

```
type IsAmbiguous<T> = T extends { isString: infer K } ? IsEqual<K,boolean> extends true ? T : never : never;

function doThing(val: number,    opts: { isString: true }): string;
function doThing(val: number,    opts: { isString: false }): number;
function doThing<T>(val: number, opts: IsAmbiguous<T>): string | number;
```

The first two overload functions predict the return type from the narrow typing of the passed in option. Whereas, in the third overload function, `opts` may be passed through a variable, in which case the type of `isString` is boolean and the return type will be determined at runtime by `doThing` implementation, but cannot (or may not) be known at compile time by the TypeScript compiler.

What is the implementation of IsEqual?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question.

```
type IsEqual<Type1,Type2> = (Type1 | Type2) extends (Type1 & Type2) ? true : never;
```

The key to testing for type equality is to use the intersection (`&`)
and union (`|`) operators. We test if the union of two types extends
the intersection of the two types. In TypeScript (and JavaScript) `subtype extends supertype` means that `subtype` is a more specific type
and `supertype` is a more general type. With objects and classes, this often means
adding a property or a method to the derived type. With scalar types, this means the subtype
is a specific value (`3.14 extends number`).

Here, `IsEqual` takes a more general type (union)
and tests if it extends a more narrow type (intersection). If it does extend, then
the two types must be equal because nothing extra was added in by either
type. If some extra type were introduced, the supertype would be more narrow than
the subtype, and therefore could not be extended.

Here are some examples of narrow and general extends.

```
var goo: string | number extends string ? true : false                  = false;
var boo: true extends boolean ? true : false                            = true;
var too: { x: number } extends { x: number, y: number } ? true : false  = false;
var woo: { x: number, y: number } extends { x: number } ? true : false  = true;
```

Here's a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgUQI4FcCGAbAPAFXBARgBo9IAmAPigF4oAKUwqAHykbIEooIAPYCAHYATOPUYEoAMjb5OUAPxRgAJxTQAXFAEQAbhGUBuALAAoUwHpzMyFGToMSiHGBxTOtMqgB7ANYFNsIiomFjaespEUFHRMWH6FAYxSclRlkqqEG4e3j5kAfB2IQBGXl4YEGgCkSklZRUCCSlNaSpqWZ6%20AMz5QfZYzsoAlgIA5tUpA8MjjU0pLRntOQAsPYXYteWV40kAZphwEMytEDOzUPNtJu4dPgCsq8HYcRFnexgHksensxeZV9m%20ABsDz6AG8dqVNBt6gBfSLgyHQyow75JX6mCxWRhQAByXmAtkejmcrn%20nm0SH8gTWWCRVSabwOqLOqSsz0WFLy1MeWEZEG2yTpzJ%20bN0%20g5ECQ3W5fTpAuifKOGWYKGEEB2wwgQhmaXZZK0kpWMpCCK8UNKmwEcKgps0xxRiTOurFygxJjSADFVQBjYCDLwCbzhDBeNBCbg8NAAWzA5VMoBs8AAglGioMRigvCg4LgqLQcBH%20MJRKCoIM4ABlFRTTTDHb6KAAaSgMIUxuwjaIQsLghE6TUbYLmmeUGHLuMZhMOx9foDUCEXhwAAspnR3BhhyhU-ptl4wC5NKXy1WhqM7RkWxxNJNRhPpwJff7Awvl6v15vty9onuDzay5XqzPKA%20UvD8in0O8ZyfedFxXUZczXTAwJ3bx9zgTRk1TdNM2zXMrygG8RhYLQt3Aww3XvR85xfOCRkQjcSM-SIf3Qv9j0AkZzTqSpQIIjjiIEUjxRMUFTBiZQIGAFBlEDFiADp2NPIjFHXOTgC8E9Vy4TR1wnGE3TSBAeFjQZvUGAkEymbwdlQlxFl8AB2a9%20NoGjV06OSCCWeF-00oDjkvR1zisXx7J8AAOZDPFc2D3M87y2IApTNBAmEOEdNJQsnTL9wkEZJNENAoAAd0GIQGwTaA6DpDh7NymhEr8zj%202gGEJ2ubhlGUe4%20KUhq3NGOhATkshwuY3L0pZNErH0ZQvFdfVfAATmcvrWEEz9%20tiwbhtG8bgAISa5hCnwDKsHEPDm4rbLIJR8CULwlCXaAoy8ZwCMgMyNW9KAwDeuBBiKcooGzKyAHI0FEb0A2cMG6uAW7aCPJKaxalsoEhqBoYEZx2oBHwk1WqyYtfHaRrGm6jqm6JMtOkwgA) with the `IsEqual` implementation and examples of its use.

In preparing this Q&A, I found [this medium article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/typescript-union-type-to-intersection-type-a785dec31fd) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993654) to be quite helpful.

Comment: `type result = IsEqual<{ readonly a: 'A' }, { a: 'A' }>;`
`result` here is true, was that your intention>

Comment: @annes thanks for your comment. Although not my intention, I'm not sure it matters as the question has been closed as a duplicate and the linked answer has a better method for computing IsEqual.