# Does typeof typeguard not work when assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I get a error when I use a `typeof` like below.

```
function func (variable: number | string) {
    const is_number = (typeof variable === 'number');
    let variable2: number,
        variable3: string;

    if (is_number)
        variable2 = variable;
        => Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
           Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    else
        variable3 = variable;
        => Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
           Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
}
```

However, there is no error like below.

```
function func (variable: number | string) {
    let variable2: number,
        variable3: string;

    if (typeof variable === 'number')
        variable2 = variable;
    else
        variable3 = variable;
}
```

[URL for test](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20func%20(variable%3A%20number%20%7C%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%09const%20is_number%20%3D%20(typeof%20variable%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%3B%0D%0A%09let%20variable2%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%09%09variable3%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09if%20(is_number)%0D%0A%09%09variable2%20%3D%20variable%3B%0D%0A%09else%0D%0A%09%09variable3%20%3D%20variable%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Do I always have to use it like above? Or is there any part that I have used wrong?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Correct, it doesn’t. The compiler can only go so far in recognizing these patterns.

Comment: @Ry- You should make an answer of your comment. Maybe reference the PR? I would vote for that :-)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: What PR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*@Ry- already answered the actual question in the comments. Below is a workaround for the limitation.*

It IS possible to do something similar to what you're trying to achieve with a helper function I'll call `isNumber`, that asserts whether a given argument `extends` a certain type in typescript. This provides a way to not inline a JS realm type assertion like `typeof variable === "number"` after all. Instead, the assertion is now contained in a function.

This is done using the `x is y` construct, which is called a [Type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) (You'll have to scroll down a bit). In the following snippet, the return type of `isNumber` is such a type predicate:

```js
const isNumber = (subject: any): subject is number => {
    return typeof subject === 'number';
};
```

Here, typescript can infer the type `number` from the boolean returned from `isNumber`. Now, if you use this helper function in your own `func`, all should be good:

```
function func (variable: number | string) {
    let variable2: number;
    let variable3: string;

    if (isNumber(variable)) {
        variable2 = variable;
    } else {
        variable3 = variable;
    }
}
```

Since the `if` block will only ever be executed if `isNumber(variable)` returns true, Typescript will now assume that `subject is number`. The following **pseudo code** demonstrates how the above code should be interpreted by TS:

```
if (variable is number) {
    // ...
}
```

I also found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45748366/6361314) that further explains the type predicate construct.