# What is reason to use is operator in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

What is reason to use is operator in TypeScript in this case?

```
type Species = "cat" | "dog";


interface Pet {
   species: Species
}

interface Cat extends Pet {

}

function petIsCat(pet: Pet): pet is Cat {
   return pet.species === "cat";
}
```

Why to use `pet is Cat` instead `boolean` if body returns bool type?

Comment: It helps the compiler (and Intellisense) to better understand the types in your code. What exactly baffles you in the official [Type Guard example](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html#user-defined-type-guards)?

Comment: Does it mean I can use boolean?

Comment: Run-time-wise it makes no difference (resulting JS code is the same). Dev-time-wise using `is` may help you catch potential problems with the code.

Comment: Okay, why not `is Cat {}`, but `pet is Cat {}`? Why we check double incoming pet parameter?

Comment: @OPV because the function could have more parameter, only one can be narrowed the compiler need to know which one

Comment: this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081332/what-does-the-is-keyword-do-in-typescript

Answer (score 61, accepted):

boolean is just a data type while 'is' operator is used for type-testing. Let me change your example a little bit:

```
type Species = 'cat' | 'dog';

interface Pet {
    species: Species;
}

class Cat implements Pet {
    public species: Species = 'cat';
    public meow(): void {
        console.log('Meow');
    }
}

function petIsCat(pet: Pet): pet is Cat {
    return pet.species === 'cat';
}

function petIsCatBoolean(pet: Pet): boolean {
    return pet.species === 'cat';
}

const p: Pet = new Cat();

p.meow(); // ERROR: Property 'meow' does not exist on type 'Pet'.

if (petIsCat(p)) {
    p.meow(); // now compiler knows for sure that the variable is of type Cat and it has meow method
}

if (petIsCatBoolean(p)) {
    p.meow(); // ERROR: Property 'meow' does not exist on type 'Pet'.
}
```

Of course you can use type casting:

```
(<Cat>p).meow(); // no error
(p as Cat).meow(); // no error
```

But it depends on the scenario.

---

Docs:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates
- https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: This approach is very useful when working with GraphQl Union types, you can pass objects whose type is the union and check their typename in a function, if you use it this in an if statement, the compiler will consider inside the if block you have the specific type from the union.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it is as so:

pet is Cat

- Is the function return type.
- because it has the "variable is type" syntax it is called a user defined type check
- This function return type can be used by your code "type-checker" at compile time:
  therefore:
  in your code editor equipped with some type checking software for TS, it'll display 0 compile errors and will know the type of person1 after the user-define type guard:

```
const isPerson = (object: any): object is Person => "address" in object

interface Person {
    address: string
}
// type of person1 is {address: string}
const person1 = {
    address: "rue"
}

if(isPerson(person1)){
    console.log(person1.address) // type is Person as opposed to {address: string}
} else {
    console.log("person is not a Person")
}
```

Hope that helps