# Typescript factory with generic method and inheritance, error is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance

Why is the typescript compiler not accepting the following code ? (I tried to have the code self-explanatory).

I get the following errors `Type 'Dog' is not assignable to type 'K'` and `Type 'Drone' is not assignable to type 'K'`.

I know I could use a workaround by using a union type `Dog | Drone` as the output type of my factory but it means updating the signature for each new object created. I was wondering if there was a 'generic' way of declaring this.

```
interface executeFn<I> {
  (param: I): string
}

interface Robot<I> {
  execute: executeFn<I>
}

interface BaseOrder {
  name: string
}

interface DogOrder extends BaseOrder {
  action: string
}

interface DroneOrder extends BaseOrder {
  destination: string
}

class Dog implements Robot<DogOrder> {
  execute(order: DogOrder): string {
    return 'The action is ' + order.action
  }
}

class Drone implements Robot<DroneOrder> {
  execute(order: DroneOrder): string {
    return 'The destination is ' + order.destination
  }
}

function robotFactory<T extends BaseOrder, K extends Robot<BaseOrder>>(
  param: T
): K {
  if (((param as unknown) as DogOrder).action) {
    return new Dog()
  }
  return new Drone()
}
```

Note that I also tried to change the generic method signature, but this does not solve the pb.

```
interface executeFn<I> {
  <T extends I>(param: T): string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler correctly warns you about the fact that K may not always be Dog or Drone.

```
class DroneAdversary implements Robot<DroneOrder> {
  execute(order: DroneOrder): string {
    return 'The destination is ' + order.destination
  }
}

const adversary = robotFactory<DroneOrder, DroneAdversary>({
  name: 'aaa',
  destination: 'dest'
}); // adversary type is DroneAdversary
```

I would go with an overload:

```
function isDogOrder(order: BaseOrder): order is DogOrder {
  return !!((order as DogOrder).action);
}

function robotFactoryOverload(order: DogOrder): Dog
function robotFactoryOverload(order: DroneOrder): Drone
function robotFactoryOverload(order: DogOrder | DroneOrder): Dog | Drone {
  if (isDogOrder(order)) {
    return new Dog()
  } else {
    return new Drone()
  }
}

const x = robotFactoryOverload({
  name: 'aaa',
  destination: 'sasas'
});
```

Comment: Thx @Lesiak, using the union type `Dog | Drone` as the return type works, I already mentioned this potential solution but this means updating the signature everytime you add a new type of Robot. I was hoping for a solution where I do not have to do that.

Comment: then add a type for the union `type Robot = Dog | Drone`. You have only one place to update.

Comment: And thanks for the `type predicate`, I did not know we could do that in typescript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081332/what-does-the-is-keyword-do-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Lesiak's answer, if you define a `Robot` type union then it is possible to define all of the overloads automatically which can help if you might have a lot of them.

```
type AnyRobot = Dog | Drone
type RobotForOrder<O extends BaseOrder, R = AnyRobot> = R extends Robot<O> ? R : never

function robotFactory<T extends BaseOrder> (order: T): RobotForOrder<T> 
function robotFactory<T extends BaseOrder> (order: T): AnyRobot {
  if (isDogOrder(order)) {
    return new Dog()
  } 
  return new Drone()
}
```