# Typescript return types (boolean vs 'is' vs <nothing>) differences?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I saw this post about the same question:
[What does the `is` keyword do in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081332/what-does-the-is-keyword-do-in-typescript)
where they were asking about what the difference between boolean and 'type is '. I didn't understand the top answer's broken english though and still need some help understanding it.

What is the difference between function

```
foo(type: any): type is number
```

and:

```
foo(type: any): boolean
```

and:

```
foo(type: any)
```

?

Thanks

Comment: I think the right thing to do here is clean up the answer to the other question or add to it.  I've tried to improve the English a bit, as well as provide a documentation link at the top which might give you a more canonical answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
foo(type: any)
```

This is just a plain function definition. TS will infer the type of the return value if it can.

---

```
foo(type: any): boolean
```

is a function definition, with the added assertion that the return value from `foo` should be a boolean. (If TS infers that the return value is *not* a boolean, it'll throw an error. Usually, this isn't necessary.)

---

```
foo(type: any): type is number
```

is completely different from the above two. It allows for the *caller* of `foo` to narrow down the type of the passed expression. This is called a **type guard**. For example, with this last implementation, you could do:

```
const something = await apiCall();
// something is unknown
if (foo(something)) {
  // TS can now infer that `something` is a number
  // so you can call number methods on it
  console.log(something.toFixed(2));
} else {
  // TS has inferred that `something` is not a number
}
```

You can only do the above with the `: type is number` sort of syntax - the other two definitions for `foo` will not allow for narrowing in the caller.

Comment: For the last example, then why not just use Promise<number>? Also if the function is async and you have to 'await' for it to finish then you should already have the type of the variable 'something' right? Also also, what would be the difference between just using 'instanceof' to check for the type of the parameter?

Comment: It's just an example - imagine that `apiCall` returns `Promise<unknown>` and you want to narrow down its type to a number rather than, say, a string containing an error message. `instanceof` does not check primitive types, but `typeof` does. Yes, if you just wanted to see if something was a particular primitive, using `typeof` would make more sense than a type guard - but type guards are more flexible and can be used to narrow down anything, with the logic abstracted into a function, rather than being inline.

Comment: Sweet, that helped a lot. I was accidently thinking of Java when I wrote 'instanceof' but the explanation makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This means your function expects as argument a boolean:

```js
function foo(arg: boolean){
  if(typeof arg != 'boolean'){
    Throw 'type error'
  } else {
    return arg
  }
}
```

This means your function will return a boolean:

```js
function foo(): boolean {
  return true;
}

let value: string;

value = foo();

//Type Error, variable value (type 'string') not assignable to type 'boolean'
```