# How to make an array check into a function without getting an error?

Tags: typescript

How do I turn the array check into a function, and not get an error in the code where the array check used to be?

The original function body is "start", and I intend to turn the function body into "start1". However, when I do that, an error shows up on the line as noted below.

```
type JSONRPCParams = object | any[]; // this is in another module where I cannot change the source

async function start(params: JSONRPCParams | undefined) {
    // the intention is to turn the following check into a function
   if (!params || !Array.isArray(params) || params.length === 0) {
       throw new Error('invalid parameter(s) provided');
   }
    
    const assetConfig = params[0]; // this is ok when the check is inline
}

function validateParams(params: JSONRPCParams | undefined) {
   if (!params || !Array.isArray(params) || params.length === 0) {
       throw new Error('invalid parameter(s) provided');
   }
}

async function start1(params: JSONRPCParams | undefined) {
    validateParams(params);    
    const assetConfig = params[0]; // this is not ok, when the check becomes a function
}
```

The error is:
'params' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'JSONRPCParams'.
Property '0' does not exist on type 'JSONRPCParams'.ts(7053)

I also tried writing validateParams as follows, but it doesn't work, the same error as above is seen.

```
if (params && Array.isArray(params) && params.length >= 0) {
    return;
}
throw new Error('Invalid parameter(s) provided');
```

How do I write the validateParams function so that in the start1 function, I don't get an error on the commented line?

I've researched other similar Stackoverflow questions, but they do not handle this issue.

Your expertise and help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: try `params?[0]`

Comment: Thanks, @robertotomás. That doesn't work.

Comment: Control flow analysis doesn't propagate across function boundaries. If you want `validateParams()` to act as a type guard on its argument, you can annotate it as an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5zY2m). If that meets your needs I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that CFA doesn't propagate, @jcalz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) such as the results of [truthiness checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#truthiness-narrowing) (like `if (params) { }`) or the results of [type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (like [the `Array.isArray()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)) does not propagate across function boundaries.  This is a trade-off made in order to make control flow analysis tractable for the compiler; see [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for a large discussion on this general issue.  Essentially, any narrowings that occur inside of a function body are not seen outside the function, so the check of the `params` parameter inside the body of `validateParams(xxx)` has no effect on the apparent type of `xxx` outside the function.

If you want this to happen, you need to annotate `validateParams` as an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), and tell the compiler exactly how the body narrows its argument.  For example:

```
function validateParams(params: JSONRPCParams | undefined): asserts params is any[] {
  if (!params || !Array.isArray(params) || params.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('invalid parameter(s) provided');
  }
}
```

The return type is the *assertion predicate* `asserts params is any[]`, which means that after the call to `validateParams(xxx)`, the type of `xxx` will be narrowed from some type assignable to `JSONRPCParams | undefined` to some type assignable to `any[]`.

Note that you are *informing* the compiler of how that function narrows.  The compiler does not *verify* that it does so.  You could have replaced the body of `validateParams()` with just about any logic, and there would be no compiler error.  For example, no logic at all:

```
function validateParams(params: JSONRPCParams | undefined): asserts params is any[] {
  // eh, it's probably fine
}
```

So be careful.

---

Anyway, now your `start1()` function will work as desired:

```
async function start1(params: JSONRPCParams | undefined) {
  validateParams(params);
  const assetConfig = params[0]; // okay
}
```

And you can see that `validateParams()` has the ability to narrow to something more specific than `any[]`, depending on the input:

```
const x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? [1, 2, 3] : undefined;
// const x: number[] | undefined
validateParams(x);
x
// const x: number[]
x.map(x => x.toFixed(1));
```

Here `x` has been narrowed from `number[] | undefined` to `number[]`, not just `any[]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgygeQHICUAKBhNBDATtgWwGcoBeKAewCMArCAY2CgB8psA7EAbQF0BuKAHpBUYAAsAliSlQJ7NuwriIuKAQoATAK4AbaAHcxK6AEko9Doqb0xHAObRlUIhS256EALAAoH9iIg7PRQAGZaQcASFPJEwHjAABRgeIREAFywiKiYOPjELFDhGhAhchAaAJRQAN4+UEIiTnLAEOyR0bIkwBSibvJOIRQ6OhT6cnbmRvQA1rJtPdih4YxR7HWyIVAJAITJeSTMrNsAgrj4IAB0UqfnSSnEVYdQe6kXeux24mSk5AAMVbVvPV6uJcKMoOwIPooABRM4UXAJADkcgAbtgdBINM97hAWoiiFUwGDUVjykiKnx1gBfHzrejRWJsIhEPEYaKlCbkF7ELi-fgNUSSaQkCizQytIXQGwMWYyOSYyE+Wm+bxhCKrKDozEabAtXKpO77DLwZDoLD3A6FdjFUqQyoZfys3DAEg8kUKbg8GrrCSbHbulhHG7YS7XM6ho2pR6sd1vVqfMTfP4A9YgsRg6GQ6FwsGIlHsbVYnF5PEqBKE54kskaClUoFQFUqnzqlYdIu6-WWgBMUeIJqy5oN+VYRRKZQdzOdrpLqU6nt4PobwigEDEABpZMAkW6wVRsFQdCBQmVlXTVf5AsFW+0YnEXQBGPvpTJmnKWgpju3lVMNjt6iBhyIZ9KXpRkmCdNkOQkLlZ15fkBBXMVQzPVUGXYJkAA8yCgABZPUxAufAbQoAgEiqAAeKBfguABWKAAH4oC4B9N27TcAGZvQyL8J3rFd0KwjJ2C0AgqBURdRxtcd7R8f8u32BJMNA7xMJ8ATwKgTDhNE8TcF4HxMIuAhsDAJSyAAPi0i5ugAMQkTDygSB8KkpIA)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced something similar but wanted to return a boolean instead. This is how I did it:

```
export function hasItems<T>(array: Array<T> | undefined): array is Array<T> {
  if (!array || !Array.isArray(array) || array.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

I also used this question as a reference: [What does the `is` keyword do in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081332/what-does-the-is-keyword-do-in-typescript)