How do I declare a property that exists conditionally?
My server will return the result as:
{
    code: number;
    info: string;
    data //only exists when code is 200
}

How do I define an type to say the data property only exists when code is 200?
So I write my code as
const res = await fetch(...)
const result:MyType = await res.json()
if (result.code != 200) {
   //process no data case 
} else {
  //process result.data
}

Github copilot gives me the following suggestion, which seems to work but I want to see if there is other way to do it.
type Type1 = {
    code: number;
    info: string;
    data?: string; // Optional property
}

type Type2 = Type1 & { code: 200, data: string };

// Usage:
const obj1: Type2 = { code: 200, info: "Success" }; // Error: Property 'data' is missing but I can set obj1 as Type1
const obj2: Type1 = { code: 404, info: "Not Found" }; // Valid
const obj3: Type2 = { code: 200, info: "Success", data: "Some data" }; // Valid 
 


Use a discriminated union.

Write a union? Read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Does this answer your question? Typescript: Type of a property dependent on another property within the same object

Also worth noting that there's no compile-time guarantee that your JSON response actually is MyType and you should be doing runtime checks.

I don't see how you can make this a discriminated union, unless you enumerate all non-200 codes. Can someone demonstrate what the union would look like?  (see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42876#issuecomment-783609507)

@jonrsharpe I actually checked that question before I asked mine but my data only exist when code == 200, so I don't feel they are the same. I know I should use narrowing but I can't figure it out and I hope it wouldn't too wordy

I'd say the only way to do this as written is with a user-defined type guard function, since you can't discriminate 200 from number. See this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz thanks for the comment and the playground (but I feel it is a bit wordy). I also tried github copilot and it gave me another suggestion and I have added it to my question.

@Bergi I didn't know what Discriminated Unions is. But github copilot gave me suggestion looks like Discriminated Unions (after I googled it). Was that what you referred to ?

• The edited version shows you just annotating different types for different values, but not consuming the values, which is what your question was presumably about. How would you annotate result with that code? Would it be Type1 or Type2 or Type1 | Type2? I don't see how this improves your situation. • Yes, type guard functions are "wordy", but since your union isn't really a discriminated union (because there's no way to say "all numbers except 200"), then you don't have much other choice. How shall we proceed here?

@jcalz I even think about just don't annotate my result here and const result:any = await res.json() as the following codes is quite straightforward and can speak for itself.

Seems like we're talking past each other. I'll try once more and then disengage to cut down noise: I'm trying to find out whether or not I understand your goal and should write up an answer. My suggestion looks like this. It's "wordy" because there's no way for TS to notice that result.code != 200 means that data doesn't exist directly. Your AI-generated code doesn't seem to do what you're asking for. If you annotate with any then you'll never get TS to complain if you access data on a non-200 response, which I thought was the whole point. How should I proceed?

@jcalz yes you understand my question and goal. Getting TS to complain if I access data on a non-200 response is the goal. With your suggestion I also found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081332/what-does-the-is-keyword-do-in-typescript, so I came up with a solution (my answer). Thanks.

Hmm, okay, I would have preferred to write up an answer, but I guess you've written your own. I'll disengage.

After thinking about the comments from @jcalz (his example taught me type predicates) and reading through the answer in What does the `is` keyword do in typescript?, especially the case #3 no compile error but runtime error.
As I still need to do the runtime check for data (ts narrowing can't eliminate that), so I come up a solution that is good enough (for me).
interface MyType {
    code: number,
    info: string,
    data: string | null //null is when code != 200
}

const res = await fetch(...)
const result:MyType = await res.json()
if (result.code != 200 || !result.data) {
   //process no data case 
} else {
  //process result.data
}

