How to narrow arguments with a union type?
I have an argument that is number | string, and try to derive a variable that is a number.
The following code shows what I expected to work. (That kind of thing would work in Python.)
function kg_to_lbs(arg: number | string) {
    let is_number = typeof arg === 'number';
    let arg_number: number = is_number ? arg : parseInt(arg);  // two errors
    return arg_number * 2.20462;
}

To my surprise TypeScript is so strict about types, that it does not allow my solution:
The argument passed to parseInt is not trusted to be a string:   (error TS2345)
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
And the result assigned to arg_number is not trusted to be a number:   (error TS2322)
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
Is there a usual way to do this in TS?
Or is there a way to tell TS, that I am sure what type something is?

is_number doesn't retain any information about type narrowing, it's just a boolean. If you want it to work you need to do let arg_number: number = typeof arg === 'number' ? arg : parseInt(arg);

The usual way is to inline the condition:
function kg_to_lbs(arg: number | string) {
    let arg_number: number = typeof arg === "number" ? arg : parseInt(arg);
    return arg_number * 2.20462;
}


I wonder if there is some trick to still write it in two lines

You could use a custom type predicate, but these must be functions:
function isNumber(arg: any): arg is number {
  return typeof arg === 'number';
}

function kg_to_lbs(arg: number | string) {
    let arg_number: number = isNumber(arg) ? arg : parseInt(arg);
    return arg_number * 2.20462;
}

BTW, in this particular case, you could have simply written:
function kg_to_lbs(arg: number | string) {
    return arg * 2.20462;
}

since the * operator converts its operands to numbers, and converting a string to a number parses it :-)

The isNumber function is indeed what I was looking for. (It also works inside of kg_to_lbs.) What is the arg is number part of the function? (If I know what it is, I will probably figure out what it does.)

Well, apparently its something about ... uh ... user-defined type guard functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081332/what-does-the-is-keyword-do-in-typescript

Erm, that's the type predicate my answer mentions, and the link I gave takes you straight to the official documentation of that language feature.

the assigning of is_number variable does not cast type assertion to arg variable, thus you are getting the error, to narrow the type correctly either use if else statement or ternary operator where the condition is typeof arg === "number"

That works. Unfortunately it is less readable. I wonder if there is some trick to still write it in two lines.

I mean, using ternary operator saves you a line of code (the line where you declare is_number arg_number = typeof arg === "number" ? arg : parseInt(arg);

Yes, I save a line. But I think two lines would be more readable. Maybe I could use a function that returns the boolean, instead of the boolean itself? Defining arg_number in an if-else statement does not work. Although it is declared in the if block and in the else block, the variable is not found after them. I would have to use it in the blocks, and thus repeat myself.

you can declare the arg_number with let keyword on top of if else statement, and then assign it inside if else statement, it means it's in the scope of the kg_to_lbs function, so you can use it after the if else statement
